# "Exception occurred while dumping" - Run AVD error "Unknown Package"

Tags: java, android

I moved my android source to another laptop, in my previous laptop it worked just fine.. i copy whole project folder to not miss a file in it.

There were some error but it all fixed. And now i'm stuck when there is an error when I want to see in AVD.

**Popup message**

> Installation failed with message Invalid File: D:\xxxx\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_4.apk.
>   It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing.
>
> WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the application data!
>
> Do you want to uninstall the existing application?

And when i pressed OK here's the error said

**Error Message**

```
Unknown failure: Exception occurred while dumping:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown package: com.xxx.yyy.zzz
at com.android.server.pm.Settings.isOrphaned(Settings.java:4134)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.isOrphaned(PackageManagerService.java:18105)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.deletePackage(PackageManagerService.java:15522)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageInstallerService.uninstall(PackageInstallerService.java:888)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.runUninstall(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:792)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.onCommand(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:118)
at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:94)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onShellCommand(PackageManagerService.java:18363)
at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:468)
at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:367)
at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub.onTransact(IPackageManager.java:2387)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onTransact(PackageManagerService.java:3031)
at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:565)
Error while Installing APKs
```

TIA

Comment: I had the same issue.Restarting the emulator device and then rebuilding the project worked for me.

Comment: Wiping data on emulator solved the problem.
To perform wipe: In Android Studio invoke AVD Manager -> In Actions for emulator that doesn't work select Wipe Data